# solving $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{-x^2-12x+28}}$

Tags: integration, radicals, substitution

> $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{-x^2-12x+28}}$$

First we need to use completing the square $-(x^2+12x-28)=-(x+6)^2+64$

So we have $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{-(x+6)^2+64}}$ I know that it is a general form of $\arcsin(\frac{x+6}{8})$ but how can I solve it using substitution?

Comment: try $\sin \theta = \frac{x+6}{8}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $y=\frac{x+6}{8}$ then the integral is equivalent to
$$
\int \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}.
$$
From here you can conclude..

Answer (score 1):

Its not really necessary to go for substitution. Use basic differentiation of inverse trig functions.

$\begin{align}
\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}&=
\sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{a})+C\\
&=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{64-(x+6)^2}}\\
&=\sin^{-1}\frac{(x+6)}{8}+C
\end{align}
$

Comment: You forgot square roots in your integrals.

Comment: '@mickep, Thanks.The answer does not change much though,but thanks again.'